# Java Html Line Break Eclipse UI Textfield

Tags: java, html, eclipse

I'm having an issue using html to set a line break in a Eclipse  UI Textfield
Here's what I have:

```
tfCharacterDescription.setText(
              "<html><div style='text-align: center;'>This is a human. <br>"
                + "The Humans has been good Warriors for centuries <br>"
                + "but they just cant get the hang of using a <br>"
                + "bow the right way.</html>"
               );
```

I'm not sure if this is how its done but I can't seem to find anything that says otherwise.

Comment: Try ``<br />`` instead of ``<br>``. Or try to seperate the lines with paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

**JTextfield NOT SUPPORT HTML tags!
Instead use in JTextPane:**

```
JTextPane tfCharacterDescription = new JTextPane();
tfCharacterDescription.setBounds(12, 12, 320, 110); //set the size
tfCharacterDescription.setContentType("text/html");//This is essential!
tfCharacterDescription.setText(
        "<html><div style='text-align: center;'>This is a human. <br>"
        + "The Humans has been good Warriors for centuries <br>"
        + "but they just cant get the hang of using a <br>"
        + "bow the right way.</html>"
    );
```